# Strapi issue when uploading image to Media Library

Tags: png, strapi

I'm trying to upload a simple `.png` format image to the `Media Library` throw Strapi Dashboard.

The issue is after the image is successfully uploaded, It has some wired holes init.

[image: The image after uploading it]

[image]

If anyone has an idea why this behavior is happening I would appreciate it!